# ERRO na leitura de um arquivo DBF

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, windows

Estou tentando ler um arquivo .dbf e usei o tutorial desse link https://www.macoratti.net/12/04/c_dbf1.htm como base mas na hora da execução está dando o erro da imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já procurei em diversos sites sobre esse tipo de erro e não achei nada semelhante ou que funciona-se. Será que é problema é na fonte de dados OBDC ? Se for, sabem como resolver ? Ou é o código ? Preciso de uma luz kk

Esse o código abaixo é onde faço a conexão:

```
 public static DataTable GetDataTableDBF(string strFileName)
    {
        OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=" + Path.GetFullPath(strFileName).Replace(Path.GetFileName(strFileName), "") + ";Exclusive=No");
        conn.Open();
        string strConsulta = "SELECT * FROM [" + Path.GetFileName(strFileName) + "]";
        OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(strConsulta, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
```

Comment: sugiro ir no site https://www.connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro/  e ver se a sua string de conexão está ok, ou tentar outros exemplos

Comment: Já conferia string nesse site e não parece estar errada. :/

Comment: lá no site com o tutorial não tem uma sessão de perguntas? talvez o autor consigo ajudar tbm

Comment: Pior que não essa sessão @RicardoPontual